# ColdFusion CFQuery block as per postgres

Tags: postgresql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, postgresql-9.1

I have not been able to get this code block to run my query against postgres in CFQuery of ColdFusion:

```
<cfquery name="uiCustomColumn" datasource="#arguments.dsn#">
    DECLARE resultValue int;
    DECLARE nextId bigint;
    BEGIN
        IF (( select count( udc_id ) from user_defined_column WHERE udc_is_active = true ) >= 10) THEN
            INSERT INTO user_defined_column(udc_id)
            VALUES(<cfqueryparam value="#this.getLabel()#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="25">)
        END IF;
    END;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Not been able to get what is the problem with above code , is this syntactically incorrect as per postgres or something else?

Comment: I have added the `ColdFusion` tag to your question so more people will see it.

Comment: are you receiving an error message or how do you know it's not working?

Comment: @Satish - As others have said, you need to elaborate. Just saying it does not run, does not tell us anything :) If you are getting an error, please post it. If you are getting different results than you expected, post a brief summary of what *is* happening now - versus what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: With cfquery, some databases such as sql server allow multiple sql commands, separated by semicolons, in a single cfquery block.  Others, such as oracle, do not.  I do not know about postgres.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: Postgres does allow multiple SQL commands within a `cfquery`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is [`plpgsql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html) syntax (the default PostgreSQL procedural language), not SQL.

You'd need to wrap this in a [`DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) command or [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) with it.
Or rewrite it with SQL syntax. Something along these lines:

```
INSERT INTO user_defined_column(udc_id)
SELECT <this.getLabel()>
WHERE (
   SELECT count(udc_id) > 9
   FROM   user_defined_column
   WHERE  udc_is_active
   )
```

Comment: +1. Just curious, but is this part of the subquery valid syntax or just typo? ie `SELECT count(udc_id) > 9` ? I am not real familiar postgresql, but it looks similar to how a `having` clause operates. Is that really possible in postgresql?

Comment: @Leigh: Yes, it's valid. The expression `count(udc_id) > 9` yields a boolean value that fits the `WHERE` clause. Since there are no non-aggregated items in the `SELECT` list, `GROUP BY` can be omitted, and *all* qualifying rows of the subquery are aggregated. You *could* write it with a `HAVING` clause and just `SELECT TRUE` as well. Or, cleaner, as an `EXISTS` semi-join ...

Comment: Ahh, I had not thought of it that way. That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I am restricted to not to write functions for this query, As I am having thousands of blocks written in my application of coldfusion which are working as per SQL-Server, now the only left a option in front of me is that I have to change these type of CFQuery blocks as per postgres , As My application says I cannot change thousands of CFQuery blocks into functions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter :I think you are asking me to change CFQuery block with equilavent postgres function?

Comment: @SatishSharma: Not sure what the confusion is. I wrote: `Or rewrite it with SQL syntax` and presented an equivalent SQL query. You cannot use plpgsql commands in this place.